# how to change the format of curdate()

Tags: php

i want to display the total value for the current month. in my  date field (entrydate), i am using the m/d/Y format; however, i have try using the following code but it's not working.please help

```
$query8 ="SELECT amount FROM pgoods WHERE MONTH(entrydate) = MONTH(CURDATE())  YEAR(entrydate) = YEAR(CURDATE())";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query8);              
            $amou = '';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $amount1= "".$row["amount"]."";
            $amou += $amount1;
            }
```

Comment: It's not working and your pc explodes?

Comment: Your query seems a bit off. try inserting AND between `MONTH(entrydate) = MONTH(CURDATE())` and `YEAR(entrydate) = YEAR(CURDATE())`

Comment: Wait, why are you counting the values using String? `$amou = 0;` and then `$amount1= floatval($row["amount"]);` (or `intval()`) should work. Plus, what @darthaditya said.

Comment: i simply want to display the the sum of  money from the amount column for the current month. i am using the entrydate column which contains the date of entry to evaluate. the format for entrydate is in this form: m/d/Y

Answer (score 0):

try this it will give you only month

```
DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%M %Y')
```

Comment: how do i use this in my case?

Comment: i try this, but it's still not working: $query8 ="SELECT amount,date_format(entrydate,'%m/%d/%Y') FROM pgoods WHERE DATE_FORMAT(entrydate, '%m/%d/%Y') = (CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y') AND   DATE_FORMAT(entrydate, '%m/%d/%Y') = (CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%Y')";